# How to make partial working in view which is inside another View in MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have View `Department` which is inside another view `Company`.In View `Department`, there are Partials loaded based on button click.

Problem is that, now on button click `Select`, the partials are not loaded. it has become unresponsive.

`Department` view is loading inside `Company` view but in the department view, If click on `Select`. It does not open Partials.

Please suggest me the way.

Company Model

```
public class ClsCompany
    {
        public IEnumerable<ClsDepartment> clsDepartment { get; set; }

    }
```

Controller Company

```
public ActionResult Company(ClsCompany clscompany)
{
   DepartmentDetails departmentDetails = new DepartmentDetails();      
   clscompany.clsDepartment = departmentDetails.List();
    return View(clsCompany);
}
```

View Company

```
  @model xx.xx.xx.Company.ClsCompany

         <div class="container">
            <div class="panel panel-default">                                           
                    <div class="panel-body">
             @Html.Partial("~/Views/Department/Department.cshtml", Model.clsDepartment)   

                </div>

            </div>

      </div>
```

Controller Department

```
  public ActionResult Department()
    {
    DepartmentDetails departmentDetails = new DepartmentDetails();      

       return View(departmentDetails.List());
    }
```

View Department

```
     @model IEnumerable<xx.xx.xx.Department.ClsDepartment>

                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DepartmentName)
                            </th>
                            <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DepartmentType)
                          </th>

                        </tr>

                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                              @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DepartmentName)
                                </td>
                           <th>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.DepartmentType)
                          </th>
                               <td>
                          <input class="search" type="button" value="Select"
                                       data-assigned="@item.DepartmentId" />
                            </td>

                            </tr>
                        }
                    </table>

 <div id="MyDepartment">

   @using (Html.BeginForm("Department", "Department", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myform" }))
            {
                <div id="mypartial"> </div>
               <button type="submit" id="submit">Run</button>

            }

        </div>
```

Partial Method

```
    public ActionResult DepartmentPartialView(string id)
   {

    if (Id == "FNC01")
  {
     return PartialView("~/Views/Department/_Finance.cshtml");
    }

    else if (Id == "ITC02")
    {
     return PartialView("~/Views/Department/_ITC.cshtml");
    }  
 else
    {
     return View();
    }      

}
```

Script  to load partials on button click `Select`

```
 $('.search').click(function () {              
                 var id = $(this).data('assigned');
                var route = '@Url.Action("DepartmentPartialView", "Department")?id=' + id ;
                route = encodeURI(route); 
                $('#mypartial').load(route);
}
```

Comment: _It does not open Partials_? What does happen. What errors are you getting? And what is your `DepartmentPartialView()` method?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Thank you for your response. I have added `DepartmentPartialView()`. I am not getting any error.

Comment: Your `DepartmentPartialView` cannot be correct - not all paths return an `ActionResult`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I do not understand. The same code works when I am in `Department` View.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, please help me.

Comment: How can I help if you do not tell us what is happening. Check you browser tools.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, what to check in browser tools. Please guide me. I can;t see anything there. There is no error.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, shall I write some JQuery code to display partials  on button click? I am displaying View inside another View. Please suggest me. Thank you.

Comment: You already have a script to do that

Comment: Yes but this is inside Department View. If i open department view and then if click on select then it opens partial views.

Comment: Scripts do not go in partials - they go in the main view or its layout

Comment: @StephenMuecke, And here is scenario is different. I have to display View inside 
 another View and I want to make the view functional which displays partials.

Comment: Yes I know!! Again , scripts DO NOT do in partials

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Sorry Stephen. `Department` is not partial view. This is main view which I am displaying in another Main view. All the Script is written inside `Department` View

Comment: Please show me the way to do this.

Comment: You have `@Html.Partial("~/Views/Department/Department.cshtml", Model.clsDepartment)` in your `Company` view which means it IS A PARTIAL

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Actually, I wanted to show View inside View and then I found this code. I tried different approach but no luck so I tried this way which worked for me. Itried using `@RenderPage("~/Views/Department/Department.cshtml", Model.clsDepartment)` which was not working.

Comment: @StephenMuecke,Please help me. Since noon, I am trying this but getting the way.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Good morning Stephen! Now I understood that what you are saying last night. I have moved the Script into Company View. But `var route = '@Url.Action("DepartmentPartialView", "Department")?id=' + id ;` locates in `Department/DepartmentPartialView?id=FNC01` which does not exist inside company folder. So the partial is not loading. Please guide me.

Comment: What? - Your code generates `/Department/DepartmentPartialView?id=FNC0` - with a leading forward slash which will go to to `DepartmentPartialView` method in `DepartmentController`

Comment: @StephenMuecke,Yes it is working now. Thank you for guiding me.